# Capybara::FrozenInTime error in integration specs using Rspec + Timecop + Capybara + Capybara Webkit

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara, capybara-webkit, timecop

I'm seeing an error in some integration specs, using rspec, capybara, capybara-webkit and timecop.

```
Capybara::FrozenInTime:
   time appears to be frozen, Capybara does not work with libraries which freeze time, consider using time travelling instead
```

The only gem that I know that freezes time is Timecop, but I'm not using it in the test case that fails.

Since the error occurs only sometimes I can't even know if its gone or not after changing something.

Comment: This is an awesome error message!

Comment: I get this error when stubbing Time#now and similar. Switching to Timecop, and making sure Timecop really returns, seems to solve it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution I found was to add

```
before :each do
  Timecop.return
end
```

in spec_helper.rb.

This way we garantee that the time is not frozen before each test, although the only ones that have this problem are the ones executed in a webdriver different from `rack-test`. In my case `capybara-webkit`.

Comment: Is it possible you were not adding Timecop.return to an after block for a test where time was being frozen?

Comment: Well, I suppose I could put Timecop.return in an after block, but `Timecop.freeze` usually receives a block, that is the proc to be executed with freezed time. Supposedly the time would come back to normal after the block closure.

Comment: You should enable safe mode with `Timecop.safe_mode = true` in your spec_helper. This will make it so Timecope.freeze requires a block, which means time will be unfrozen for you.

Answer (score 11):

The end of the error message holds the solution:

> consider using time travelling instead

Just change `Timecop.freeze` to `Timecop.travel`.  `Timecop.freeze` [breaks Capybara's auto-wait feature.](https://twitter.com/jonicklas/status/19886877170)

In addition, I would call `Timecop.return` in an after block, as it will be associated with the most recent travel block:

```
after :each do
  Timecop.return
end
```

Comment: The thing is: I really need to freeze time in this case. As a rule of thumb I always use travel, but there are tests that need precision in seconds